# rails audit log

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, audit

I am working with ruby on rails 3. 
I want to implement audit log.
I have gone through [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited), but I was wondering if there is any way to implement the same **without** using any gem or plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want audit at the controller/action level, here is a simple way to do it:

```
 class BankController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :audit

    private
      def audit
      # record the action and parameters in an audit log
      end
 end
```

And with inheritance, you get this accross other controllers as well:

```
class VaultController < BankController
  before_filter :verify_credentials

  private
    def verify_credentials
      # make sure the user is allowed into the vault
    end
 end
```

In the second case, :audit will be run before :verify_credentials.

Filters are detailed [here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

If you want audit at the database level with active_records, you can use Observers. [Detailed here](https://rorataspire.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/filters-and-observers-in-rails/).